# Load Various Content into Div in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am wondering how to achieve this effect in Wordpress... http://www.wendys.com/

My client would like to have various clickable areas that will load content at the top of the page like on Wendys.com

What would be the most logical way to do this in Wordpress? I've done some research and it seems like ajax would be the best way to go, but I've never used it whatsoever. Can anyone walk me through this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a website that has instructions to get you going. The point of stacks is to help you in a project, but not to write the code for you.  This will get you going in the right direction once you have it going and you have further problems come on back and I will be happy to help.

http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/external.html